# $(...).on is not a function - jQuery Error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am using dialog box, which I am closing when a user click anywhere on page expect that dialog box.

Here is my code:

```
$('body').on('click','.ui-widget-overlay',function()
{ 
    $('#myRateSettingsPopup').dialog('close'); 
});
```

Somehow its returning an error:

**$(...).on is not a function**

What is wrong with my code ?

I am using jquery-1.6.1.min.js , but I cannot update it to the latest version. I am bound.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Do you include jQuery properly? What version are you using?

Comment: There is a good chance that **you are not using the latest version of jQuery**.

Comment: I am using jquery-1.6.1.min.js. But i cannot change it to latest version

Comment: $().on introduced in jQuery 1.7 If you are using older version then tried to use jQuery.bind

Comment: Strongly recommend to use the updated jquery library. 1.8 or higher.

Comment: i guess $().live is deprecated ?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Method [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was introduced in jQuery version 1.7.

I think you have to upgrade your jQuery library to the newest version.

Otherwise, you can use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$( ".ui-widget-overlay" ).bind( "click", function(e) {
    $('#myRateSettingsPopup').dialog('close');
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: The error is removed but, Now its not closing my popup ,

Comment: @CodeHunter so you're problem is resolved, why your code doesn't work now the problem you had is fixed is another question.

Comment: Can you help my why its not closing my dialog box?

Comment: @CodeHunter can you check one thing, Run $('#myRateSettingsPopup').dialog('close'); directly in Firebug. if it will work in firebug then it will surely work in our code.

Comment: @DavidBarker $.live is removed from 1.9. I am sure people need to do patch their code  again when they migrate to 1.9+.

Comment: Yes it did close my dialog box using : $('#myRateSettingsPopup').dialog('close');

Comment: bind will only bind event handlers for currently existing items.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle I want a demo to fix your code.

Comment: i prefer upgrade ur jquery and use 'on' otherwise try with 'live'

Comment: Try to remove  e.stopPropagation(); for just a test

Comment: Ok I am making a fiddle

Comment: @CodeHunter See the fix http://jsfiddle.net/sgC3w/2/  I add the bind event after open the dialog.

Answer (score 8):

The replacement for .on() in jQuery > 1.4.2 is [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$('body').delegate('.ui-widget-overlay', 'click', function () {
    $('#myRateSettingsPopup').dialog('close');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$( ".close" ).bind( "click", function(e) {
$('#popup1').hide();
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

jquery-1.7
jqueryui/1.8.2 perfect.

or your overlay

```
$( ".YOUR OVERLAY" ).bind( "click", function(e) {
$('#YOUR POPUP').hide();
   e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `live` instead of `on` its a jquery version problem

```
$('body').live('click','.ui-widget-overlay',function()
{ 
    $('#myRateSettingsPopup').dialog('close'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As jquery 1.6.1 is not supporting `on` so you can use `live`

```
$('body').live('click','.ui-widget-overlay',function(event)
{ 
          event.stopPropagation();        
          $('#myRateSettingsPopup').dialog('close'); 

});
```