# Neither .on or .live functions are recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, developer-tools

I am so frustrated right now. I have been trying for the past half hour to get `event delegation` to work. I tried using `.on` and Chrome told me that it wasn't a function.

I searched this question

[$(...).on is not a function - jQuery Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625231/on-is-not-a-function-jquery-error)

and thought it was because I was using an earlier version of JQuery. Because of that, I decided to include the latest version of JQuery from the Google Developer's website

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Here's what I included at the end of my `body` tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I thought that would solve the problem

If I click on the link under `View Source (Ctrl + u)` and click on the JQuery file, I get source code, which leads me to believe it was loaded properly.

I also tried to use the `.live` function and found out that wasn't a function either. There's almost no chance I have a syntax error either

```
$("td > a")[0].on("click", function() { alert('hi') })
```

Yet, I get the following output from the console

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].on is not a function
>       at :2:16
>       at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (:895:140)
>       at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (:828:34)
>       at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (:694:21)

I also tried copying and pasting the minified JQuery code into a JavaScript file, and including that way, but that also failed.

Is it an issue with the `Content Distribution Network(CDN)` or a problem with the version itself?

I know that `JQuery 2` only supports modern browsers, but I am using `Google Chrome`. I can not understand what the problem is.

Has anyone else ran into this problem before? Help or advice is most appreciated.

Edit:

```
`jquery.fn.jquery` returns `2.1.3`
```

Comment: Type jQuery.fn.jquery in your browser and tell me the output

Comment: That returns `2.1.3`

Comment: @RiteshK, what would I need to include besides the `script` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to apply a jQuery method to a raw DOM object. With the index specified you no longer have a jQuery object selected.

Also, the way you've structured your `on()` function doesn't employ event delegation. Try this:

```
$(document).on("td > a:eq(0)", "click", function() { alert('hi') });
```

Comment: Wouldn't 'td > a:eq(0)' be more in line with jQuery syntax?

Comment: This works perfectly! I will accept this answer in 4 minutes when I can. Thank you very much