# Jquery validation with keyup and blur together

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            //alert('hi');
            var form_name  = $('#reg_form_name');
            var reg_name = $('#reg_name');
            var reg_button = $('#register_submit');
```

I am trying to validate reg_name with keyup and blur together

I am getting following error: **Uncaught TypeError: reg_name.on is not a func**

```
            reg_name.on('keyup blur', function (e){
            validateName(reg_name, reg_name_error, 'Full name');
            });

            form_name.submit(function(){
            // alert("form submited");

            if(validateName(reg_name, reg_name_error, 'firstname'))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

            }); //form submit
```

This is the function to validate the name field

```
           function validateName(name, name_error, field_type){

                   var fname = name.val();

                   var regx_name = /^[a-z]{4,11}$/;

                   if(fname == ''){
                           name_error.html('Please enter ' + field_type);
                           return false;
                   }
                   if(regx_name.test(fname)){
                          // name_error.html('<img src="images/correct.png">');
                           name_error.html('ok');
                           return true;
                   }
                   else{
                           name_error.html('Only 4 to 10 characters allowed ');
                           return false;
                   }

           }// Validate Name function
     }); //doc ready
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21625231/3639582 `on()` was introduced after jQuery 1.7

Comment: i am using -> jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it , i used bind

```
reg_name.bind('keyup blur', function (e){
    validateName(reg_name, reg_name_error, 'Full name');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe just bite the bullet and loop it:

```
$.each(['keyup','blur']), function(){
reg_name.on(this, function (e){
            validateName(reg_name, reg_name_error, 'Full name');
            });
    form_name.submit(function(){
            // alert("form submited");

            if(validateName(reg_name, reg_name_error, 'firstname'))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

            });
}
```