# $('.close').on is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add banner after page load. I am using code below, in JSFiddle "CLOSE" button is working, but on my website it's not. It says "$('.close').on is not a function". I think it's because I don't use external jQuery file, because it's ruin my page. It's possible to do it without external jQuery? Or just with JS only?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.open').fadeIn();
    
  $('.close').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
 /* Act on the event */
        
    $('.open').fadeOut();
        
  });
});
```

```css
.open {position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 99999; display: none; opacity: 1; -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in; -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in; transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;width: 561px; height: 274px; margin: auto}

.close {background: #000; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 25px; position: absolute; right: -12px; text-align: center; top: -10px; width: 24px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; -moz-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px}

.close:hover {background: #fff; color: #000}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup" class="open">
<a href="#"><img src="https://image.zootlab.cz/cache2/scale/561x277/000/000/003/434/3434017.jpeg" /></a>
<a class="close" title="Zavřít" href="#close">X</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$(...).on is not a function - jQuery Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625231/on-is-not-a-function-jquery-error)

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this without jquery

```
document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";

document.getElementById("closeBtn").addEventListener("click", closeDialog);

function closeDialog () {
   document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
}
```

```js
document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";

document.getElementById("closeBtn").addEventListener("click", closeDialog);

function closeDialog () {
   document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.open {position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 99999; display: none; opacity: 1; -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in; -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in; transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;width: 561px; height: 274px; margin: auto}

.close {background: #000; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 25px; position: absolute; right: -12px; text-align: center; top: -10px; width: 24px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; -moz-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px}

.close:hover {background: #fff; color: #000}
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="open">
<a href="#"><img src="https://image.zootlab.cz/cache2/scale/561x277/000/000/003/434/3434017.jpeg" /></a>
<a class="close" title="Zavřít" href="#close" id="closeBtn">X</a>
</div>
```

For transititon effects do it like this

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.opacity = 1;
}, 0);

function closeDialog() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
#popup.open {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  width: 561px;
  height: 274px;
  margin: auto
}

.close {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px
}

.close:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="open">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://image.zootlab.cz/cache2/scale/561x277/000/000/003/434/3434017.jpeg" /></a>
  <a class="close" title="Zavřít" href="#close" onclick="closeDialog()">X</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's but it's not working on my test site, take a look: [link]https://216663.myshoptet.com/

Comment: @Patrik You also have to update the anchor tag ! Please check my updated answer

Comment: It's before </footer> element.

Comment: Yeah i saw that. check my previous comment. You need to update the anchor tag as well

Comment: Hm, that's weird, i copy it to HTML editor but after saving, the "onclick" will disappear :-/

Comment: Check the first snippet again. No need to add onclick on the anchor tag in that. Just add the id and bind event on that id

Comment: @Patrik Your test site is using jQuery 1.5.1. `.on` has been added in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma It works like a charm now, you are the best. Can I ask you one more question?

Fade out effect runs great but fadein not work even transition is set on 400ms, why?

And it's possible to add background overlay with 0.7 opacity? I tried it with ::before but it's not work. I tried class="overlay" too after "popup" id, but then popup doesn't work.

Comment: check second snippet again. Add settimeout to the line that shows the popup. It will work as expected. :)